# PHP get unix timestamp from string without setting default timezone

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a precise date of `1/1/2020 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles` time that I want to convert into a UNIX timestamp. Many answers out there want to set a default timezone using `date_default_timezone_set` before inserting the string into `strtotime()` function. But I do not want to mess with the default timezone of the server (which is probably UTC).

Is there anything wrong with doing `strtotime("1/1/2020 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles")` to get my timestamp?

I get the correct UNIX value this way. It's just, there's nothing in the docs to indicate this is valid.

Comment: The docs do cover the date time valid formats [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php).

Comment: @AlexBarker Thank you, this is exactly the information I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your time str has time zone, there is no need to set the default time zone. But when you want to print it, you need to set default timezone.

```
php > echo date_default_timezone_get();
UTC

php > echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("1/1/2020 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles"));
2020-01-01 08:00:00

php > echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("1/1/2020 00:00:00"));
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: This is a very good answer.  I just wanted to add that the built-in [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class can also convert timezones for you without messing around with the default timezone.  This could be useful if you need to get the timestamp back in the America/Los_Angeles timezone.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any specific list of strings allowed here? Could I have said `PST` instead of `America/Los_Angeles` to get the same answer? Docs just says "...will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp". Will try doesn't work for me. Edit: just saw Alex Barker's comment that directs to the docs.

Comment: @NamKim I added the link to a comment in your main question.  I presume any valid TZ abbreviation know by the underlying system should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

strtotime and datetime also process time zone information located in the date string. 
If omitted, the local settings of the server are used.

This provides a correct timestamp

```
strtotime("1/1/2020 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles");
```

But the output with date() uses the local time zone of the server.

These problems do not exist when the DateTime class is used. 
In the DateTime object, the time zone is stored in the object, regardless of the server's local settings.

```
echo date_default_timezone_get(); //my Server get Europe/Berlin

$dateTimeLA = date_create("1/1/2020 00:00:00", new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

echo $dateTimeLA->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e");
```

Output: **2020-01-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles**

If timestamp is needed:

```
$tsLA = $dateTimeLA->getTimeStamp();
echo $tsLA;  //1577865600
```

How to create a DateTime-Object from timestamp:

```
$dateFromTs = date_create(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$dateFromTs->setTimestamp(1577865600);
var_dump($dateFromTs);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(19) "America/Los_Angeles"
}
```